# Stylesheet not loaded on first boot because of MIME-type

Tags: java, html, css, jakarta-ee, spring-security

..this happens the first time when project is recently started.
After login for the first time and make logout- styles continue to work as needed.
Why is this happening?
P.S. Sorry for my bad english

here's what the browser console says:

> auth:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/auth'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
>   type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

SecurityConfiguration:

```
package config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).
            usersByUsernameQuery("select login,password,true from user where login=?").
             authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select login, role from user where login=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth", "/reg").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth").usernameParameter("login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/auth");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
}
```

Authorization.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Authorization</title>
    <c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="mainblock">
        <input type="hidden"
               name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
               value="${_csrf.token}"/>

        <form method="post" action="/auth">
            User Name : <input type="text" name="login">
            Password : <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
<input name = "submit" value = "Authorize" type = "submit" />
        </form>

        <p>Did not create an account?

            <a href="/reg">Registration</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The styles file is in the "web" package along with Authorizatiom.jsp

Comment: "doesn't work" -- what does this mean. Please read [ask] to learn what is on-topic here.

Comment: If the answer was a simple typo or coding error the please delete the question. If the fix is likely to help others then please improve the question and write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this was due to my carelessness and the specified wrong directory, which is specified in configure (WebSecurity web). I needed to add "vendor / **"
Also i defined the content path: `<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "$ {pageContext.request.contextPath} /vendor/css/styles.css">`